# Notation of Set without arg max element?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have a set $A = \{a, b, c\}$ and a function that determines a value for a given element $f(x) = {value}$. Next I need the max value of all of the elements from the function:
$$a_{max} = \max_{x\in A}(f(x))$$ The problem comes with the next step where I need a set that contains all elements from $A$ without the element that produced the maximum value. So if e.g. $a_{max} = f(b)$, then I need a set $B = \{a, c\}$.

How would I write down this scenario $A, x \notin \{\operatorname{arg\,max}_x f(x)\}$ ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One solution which I would consider more or less elegant is the following:

$$B = \{x \in A \mid \exists y \in A: f(y) > f(x)\}$$

Comment: Nice definition.

Comment: Aaah, that's very elegant.. thanks!

Answer (score 5):

How about $$B=A\setminus f^{-1}(\max_{x\in A}(f(x)))?$$

Comment: If I understand this right, the inverse function of the maximum value returns the element for which the maximum was reached? And then it's simply set A without that element?

Comment: Is this the same as $B = A \setminus \operatorname{arg\,max}_x f(x)$

Comment: @ThomasFankhauser, the problem is, you can have "ties". Thus, it depends how you define that expression. If $\mbox{arg max } f$ is defined as the set of all $x$ such that $f(x) = \mbox{max } f$, then yes. If $\mbox{arg max } f$ is defined as the the unique $x$ such that $f(x) = \mbox{max } f$, then no, since after all, this expression needn't be well-defined. However, it *is* true that for all functions such that the latter definition "works", it agrees with the former definition.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you want, but here's my take.

Let $A$ denote a set with $n$ elements, $T$ denote a totally ordered set, and assume $f : A \rightarrow T$ is an injective function.

Then we can define a sequence of sets $B_{i \leq n}$ and a sequence of functions $g_{i \leq n}  : B_i \rightarrow T$ by recursion as follows.

Base Case. $B_0 = A, g_0 = f$.

Inductive Step. $B_{i+1} = B_i \setminus \{\mbox{arg max}\, g_i\},$ and $g_{i+1} = g_i \restriction B_{i+1}$

I may have stuffed up the end-cases a little, so don't use the above definition uncritically!!